# Prolog: Rotate list n times right

Tags: prolog

Working on a predicate, `rotate(L,M,N)`, where `L` is a new list formed by rotating `M` to the right `N` times.

My approach was to just append the tail of `M` to its head `N` times.

```
rotate(L, M, N) :- 
   (  N > 0,
      rotate2(L, M, N)
   ;  L = M
   ).

rotate2(L, [H|T], Ct) :- 
   append(T, [H], L), 
   Ct2 is Ct - 1, 
   rotate2(L, T, Ct2).
```

Currently, my code returns `L` equal to the original `M`, no matter what `N` is set to.
Seems like when I'm recursing, the tail isn't properly moved to the head.

Comment: Hint: you can do this much more efficiently with just two calls to `append`.

Comment: @larsmans Do you mean only two calls to append? Do I need to be continually decreasing N?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `append` to split lists, and `length` to create lists:

```
% rotate(+List, +N, -RotatedList)
% True when RotatedList is List rotated N positions to the right
rotate(List, N, RotatedList) :-
    length(Back, N),           % create a list of variables of length N
    append(Front, Back, List), % split L
    append(Back, Front, RotatedList).
```

Note: this only works for N <= length(L). You can use arithmetic to fix that.

**Edit for clarity**
This predicate is defined for *List* and *N* arguments that are not variables when the predicate is called. I inadvertently reordered the arguments from your original question, because in Prolog, the convention is that strictly input arguments should come before output arguments. So, *List* and *N* and input arguments, *RotatedList* is an output argument. So these are correct queries:

```
?- rotate([a,b,c], 2, R).
?- rotate([a,b,c], 1, [c,a,b]).
```

but this:

```
?- rotate(L, 2, [a,b,c]).
```

will go into infinite recursion after finding one answer.

When reading the SWI-Prolog documentation, look out for predicate arguments marked with a "?", as in [`length`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2). They can be used as shown in this example.

Comment: I'm not seeing how to make this work for `N > length(L)`. Seems like it would need some kind of recursive call to rotate while changing/tracking the value of N. But that seems like over complicating things.

Comment: @AdamDuvall Modular arithmetic

Comment: So, currently it times out if `N > length(L)`, is the idea that there is some way to use mod so that it stops at some point and doesn't time out?

Comment: I get that rotating it `length(L) + 1` times is the same as rotating it once. I just don't get the translation of that into prolog syntax. By timing out, I mean `?- rotate(L, [1,2,3,4], 5).` results in the program timing out rather than evaluating false, or incorrectly.